# Is there an api status page for LinkedIn anywhere?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have encountered several instances where it appears that the official LinkedIn api is down or is responding very slowly. There is no api status page that I can find however (something like http://status.twitter.com/) so I have no way to narrow down the problem.

Is there one hidden somewhere that I have not found, or does it just not exist?

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: https://linkedin.statuspage.io/

Comment: There is no way that this would attract an "opinionated answer" or spam. It should not have been closed. This question certainly has an actual, factual answer.